# crystal formula to compare a string field and a number field

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula

I'm trying to compare two fields that contain up to 2 digit field. 
One formula field is a {string} the other to compare to is a {number} field. 
But i"m running to a problem when the string field shows for example "08" and the number field shows "8" then it will show 1 that there is a differences but actually there is no difference. If the string field shows 14 and the number field shows 14 that works perfectly but anything between 1-9 will show a difference when actually there is no difference.
This is what I tried so far.

```
If {number.field} = 0 
Then StringVar AdjustValue:= " " 
Else StringVar AdjustValue:= totext ({number.field},0,"")
;
if {@stringfield} = StringVar AdjustValue then 0 else 1
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, convert from string to numeric so you don't have to worry about leading zeros.

```
if tonumber({@stringfield})={number.field} then 0 else 1
```

And just a quick side note: You are re-declaring the AdjustValue variable three times. There's no need to refer to it via "StringVar" after an initial variable declaration within the same formula.

EDIT: Since you're having problems with the top formula, you could also try the alternative of just padding your AdjustValue variable to two spaces:

```
stringvar AdjustValue;
If {number.field} = 0 
Then AdjustValue:= " " 
Else AdjustValue:= totext ({number.field},"00") //add padding
;
if {@stringfield} = StringVar AdjustValue then 0 else 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm getting a error and I apologize that I did not say that the {@stringfield} is part of a totext formula, so when I use your formula I get a error for the {@totext} formula I'm using that adds all {@stringfields} + {@stringfields} in the {@totext} to suppress {@totext} = 0 in a group section.

Comment: @Dagz200 What is your exact error and from which formula? Can you post the other formulas you're talking about? I don't think I'm quite understanding the issue.

Comment: When I try to run the report with the formula you recommended CR pops up the Format Formula Editor - Suppress highlighting the (@text) formula.

Comment: The {@text} formula is basic, {@stringfields1} + {@stringfields2} + {@stringfields3} + {@stringfields4}. If the {@text} > 0 to suppress the line. In each string field formula I have: if {@Phone} = totext ({phone.field}) then 0 else 1. The {@phone} formula I have:

Comment: if {number.field} = '98'
or {number.field} = "  " // (2 character spaces in "  ")
then "  " else {number.field}

Comment: all of this is being put into a text string formula for a text export if the field isnull it will contain the character length between other string formula fields.

Comment: @Dagz200 See my edit. I'm not sure how your error is related to my original formula, sorry.

Comment: thanks that worked something so simple. I think I was just over thinking it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple with a formula field that will return a Boolean value:

```
// {@compare}
ToNumber({@string})={number.field}
```

Reference the `{@compare}` where ever you need it.